# CSS or JS for making select not flow out of screen to the right

Tags: html, css

If having a select element (aka. drop down list) by the right side of the browser window, and setting the width to be less than what the option texts actually take up, then clicking the drop down list so it expands will render some of the options text outside the browser window. If the browser is maximized this means that not all the text is visible.

Demonstrating html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="text-align: right;">
<select style='width: 100px;'>
<option> Long, long (quite long) text </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

So how is that avoided? Can I set some css property so that the expanded options will align to the right side of the box and flow left?

Or do I need to use some js-library for customized comboboxes/drop down lists?

Thanks!

Comment: As a fyi, a select element is not really a [combobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box)

Comment: You are right. I have edited the post to replace "combobox" with "drop down list". Thanks.

Comment: That's right, a select is just a drop down menu. That aside, i'd like to know as well without having to resort to java library.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="text-align: right;">
<select style='width: 100px;' dir="rtl">
<option> Long, long (quite long) text </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

The key would be the **dir="rtl"**

Answer (score 0):

Sexy Combo (jQuery plugin, http://code.google.com/p/sexy-combo/) can have it's css changed to let the box flow to the left. The changes depend on the selected theme, but with the default "sexy" theme, here is a guide. First decide the width of the collapsed selector box and the width of the expanded selector (I have chosen 100px and 200px). Then do the following changes in the "sexy" skin's css file:

```
div.sexy {          width: 100px; } /* coll. width */
div.sexy input {    width:  83px; } /* coll. width - icon width, (100 - 17) */
div.sexy div.icon { left:  100px; } /* coll. width */
div.sexy div.list-wrapper {
                    left: -100px;   /* coll. width - exp. width, (100 - 200) */
                    width: 200px;   /* exp. width */
}
```

It you want the default flow to the right, set the left property of "div.list-wrapper" to 0px instead.

I do not know if this is more or less elegant than with other combo plugins.

Advantages: (over Tony Joyce's answer) When collapsed the first part of the string is shown, not the last. Furthermore it is indeed a combo box, and lets the user type to find what he is looking for. Supports ajax, if desired.

Disadvantages: Depending on JS, jQuery and Sexy Combo. Slower. Does not use os theme, i.e. will not look like a Mac OS style drop down menu on such a computer, but will look the same on all.